# Create dispatch_time_t with NSTimeInterval

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `NSTimeInterval` value, I need to create a `dispatch_time_t` value with it. This is what I tried:

```
let timeInterval : NSTimeInterval = getTimeInterval()

//ERROR: Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSTimeInterval' and 'UInt64'
let dispatch_time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(timerInterval * NSEC_PER_SEC))
```

I understand this error message, but I don't know how to get rid of it. Could someone please provide some suggestions? How can I create a `dispatch_time` instance with `NSTimeInterval`? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
    Int64(0.3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //... Code
}
```

You can try this, this works fine with me.

In your code just replace your last line with:

```
let d_time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(timeInterval * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
```

Comment: Why you replace my `NSTimeInterval` value to 0.3? I konw this works, it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively:

`let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(5)`

Answer (score 2):

You have:

> let timeInterval : NSTimeInterval = getTimeInterval()
>
> let dispatch_time =
>   dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(timeInterval * NSEC_PER_SEC))

And you are receiving the following error:

```
ERROR: Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands
of type 'NSTimeInterval' and 'UInt64'
```

As a result, you will need to **cast** or **change** the variables types in your `Int64(timeInterval * NSEC_PER_SEC)` equation so that they have compatible data types.

- `timeInterval` is a `NSTimeInterval` which is an alias of type **`Double`**
- `NSEC_PER_SEC` is an **`UInt64`**
- The `dispatch_time` function is expecting an **`Int64`** argument

Therefore, the error will go away by changing the `NSEC_PER_SEC` to a `Double` so that it matches the data type of `timeInterval`.

```
let dispatch_time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
    Int64(timeInterval * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
```

---

Another random point: you will likely get a `Variable used within its own initial value` error when you name your variable `dispatch_time` when calling `dispatch_time`.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very simple, ever since Xcode 8:

```swift
let dispatchTime = (DispatchTime.now() + timeInterval).rawValue
```

Answer (score 0):

DispatchTime in Swift 3/4/5 have a '+' operator for Double AKA TimeInterval

```
let delay: TimeInterval = 2.0
let dispatchTime: DispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + delay
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1780550